# I cannot use Ants profiler with interop app on (only) my machine

Tags: c#, profiling, winforms-interop, red-gate-ants

I'm attempting to use the Red Gate Ants Performance Profiler for an application on my machine. When I run the profiler, I get the error below for every mouse or keyboard click (thus making it impossible to profile my application with that tool). According to to Red Gate, I'm the only one to ever report or see this issue. None of my coworkers have the problem on their machines. I tried the profiler version 7, 7.2, 7.4, 8.0, 8.2, 8.3. The problem does not occur for me unless I'm using mixed WPF and WinForms applications. What particular setting on my machine would cause this issue?

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void <Module>._ANTS_EnteringProfilerSection()'.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Did you try reinstalling VS and the Frameworks?

Comment: I have not reinstalled VS or the Frameworks. I installed VS2012 after having VS2010 for some time. The problem did not go away then, but I suppose that doesn't do any kind of .NET 4.0 repair. Do I dare run a .NET 4.0 repair after having installed VS2012?

Comment: Go ahead and reinstall .NET 4, and its updates! If the problem occurs exclusively in you PC, that might be it. (We are at the .NET 4.5.1 by now)